Excel InputBox: name shapes with unique names
This code allows you to add 2 shapes "oval" to a selected cell range and rename the shapes.
It uses 3 InputBoxes:

"1/3 Select Shape Range"
"2/3 Enter Shape Name shp1"
"3/3 Enter Shape Name shp2"

How do you build the "Enter Shape Name"-InputBox to ensure a unique name is given to every shape and have a MsgBox saying "This name is already taken"?
Option Explicit

'========================================================================
' InputBox: Add Shapes for Buttons v3
'========================================================================
' Buttons: 2
' Cell Size: Width 47
' Button Size: DIA
' Line Weight: LWT
' Shape Type: msoShapeOval, No 9
'========================================================================

Sub IPB_AddShapes_Buttons_v3()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape

Const DIA As Single = 9
Const LWT As Single = 1

On Error Resume Next

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set rng = Application.InputBox(Title:="1/3 Select Shape Range", _
                               Prompt:="", _
                               Type:=8)

  Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, _
                                rng.Left + 5, _
                                rng.Top + ((rng.Height - DIA) / 2), _
                                DIA, _
                                DIA)
    With shp1
        .Name = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                                     Default:="Click L1 ", _
                                     Prompt:="", _
                                     Type:=2)
        .Shadow.Visible = False
        .Fill.Visible = True
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        .Line.Visible = False
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        .Line.Weight = LWT
        .Line.Transparency = 0
    End With
    
  Set shp2 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, _
                                rng.Left + 19, _
                                rng.Top + ((rng.Height - DIA) / 2), _
                                DIA, _
                                DIA)
    With shp2
        .Name = Application.InputBox(Title:="3/3 Enter Name Level 2", _
                                     Default:="Click L2 ", _
                                     Prompt:="", _
                                     Type:=2)
        .Shadow.Visible = False
        .Fill.Visible = True
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        .Line.Visible = False
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        .Line.Weight = LWT
        .Line.Transparency = 0
    End With  
    
  MsgBox "Shape Names:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "" & shp1.Name & vbNewLine & _
               "" & shp2.Name, , ""
    
End Sub
'========================================================================

EDIT
@taller presents two solutions.
This is the first solution, using:

"Add an UDF to validate user's input."
"Another option UDF"

The user has one retry to name the shapes with a unique name. Two message boxes inform the user. MsgBox 1: if the name entered is a duplicate, the user is asked to retry. MsgBox 2: if the retry failed, the user is asked to restart.
Everything works perfectly.
Option Explicit

'========================================================================
' InputBox: Add Shapes for Buttons v3 UPDATE v0
'========================================================================
' Buttons: 2
' Cell Size: Width 47
' Button Size: DIA
' Line Weight: LWT
' Shape Type: msoShapeOval, No 9
'========================================================================

Sub IPB_AddShapes_Buttons_000_v3_UPDATE_v0()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape

Const DIA As Single = 9
Const LWT As Single = 1

On Error Resume Next

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set rng = Application.InputBox(Title:="1/3 Select Shape Range", _
                               Prompt:="", _
                               Type:=8)

  Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, _
                                rng.Left + 5, _
                                rng.Top + ((rng.Height - DIA) / 2), _
                                DIA, _
                                DIA)
    With shp1
        Dim sName As String
        sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                                     Default:="Click L1 ", _
                                     Prompt:="", _
                                     Type:=2)
        If Not ValidateName(sName) Then
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated."  _
            & vbCrLf & "Please try again.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate"
            sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                                         Default:="Click L1 ", _
                                         Prompt:="", _
                                         Type:=2)
        End If
        If ValidateName(sName) Then
            .Name = sName
            .Shadow.Visible = False
            .Fill.Visible = True
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Visible = False
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Weight = LWT
            .Line.Transparency = 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is already taken."  _
            & vbCrLf & "Please restart.", vbExclamation, "Restart"
            .Delete
        End If
    End With
    
  Set shp2 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, _
                                rng.Left + 19, _
                                rng.Top + ((rng.Height - DIA) / 2), _
                                DIA, _
                                DIA)
    With shp2
'        Dim sName As String
        sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="3/3 Enter Name Level 2", _
                                     Default:="Click L2 ", _
                                     Prompt:="", _
                                     Type:=2)
        If Not ValidateName(sName) Then
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated."  _
            & vbCrLf & "Please try again.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate"
            sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="3/3 Enter Name Level 2", _
                                         Default:="Click L2 ", _
                                         Prompt:="", _
                                         Type:=2)
        End If
        If ValidateName(sName) Then
            .Name = sName
            .Shadow.Visible = False
            .Fill.Visible = True
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Visible = False
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Weight = LWT
            .Line.Transparency = 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is already taken."  _
            & vbCrLf & "Please restart.", vbExclamation, "Restart" 
            .Delete
        End If
    End With
    
  MsgBox "Shape Names:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "" & shp1.Name & vbNewLine & _
               "" & shp2.Name, , ""
    
End Sub
'========================================================================

Function ValidateName(ByVal ShpName As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ShpName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ValidateName = (s Is Nothing)
End Function
'========================================================================

This is the second solution, using:

"User may retry X times"

The user has X retries to name the shapes with a unique name.
Issue: The shp-1-"try again"-prompt works properly. The shp-2-"try again"-prompt has unlimited retries.
Option Explicit

'========================================================================
' InputBox: Add Shapes for Buttons v3 UPDATE v1
'========================================================================
' Buttons: 2
' Cell Size: Width 47
' Button Size: DIA
' Line Weight: LWT
' Shape Type: msoShapeOval, No 9
'========================================================================

Sub IPB_AddShapes_Buttons_000_v3_UPDATE_v1()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape

Const DIA As Single = 9
Const LWT As Single = 1

Dim sName As String, iCnt As Long
Const MAX_TRY = 3  ' max tries

On Error Resume Next

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set rng = Application.InputBox(Title:="1/3 Select Shape Range", _
                               Prompt:="", _
                               Type:=8)

  Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, _
                                rng.Left + 5, _
                                rng.Top + ((rng.Height - DIA) / 2), _
                                DIA, _
                                DIA)
    With shp1
'        Dim sName As String, iCnt As Long
'        Const MAX_TRY = 3  ' max tries
        Do
            If Len(sName) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated."  _
                & vbCrLf & "Please try again.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate"
            End If
            sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                                         Default:="Click L1 ", _
                                         Prompt:="", _
                                         Type:=2)
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
        Loop Until ValidateName(sName) Or iCnt = MAX_TRY
        If ValidateName(sName) Then
            .Name = sName
            .Shadow.Visible = False
            .Fill.Visible = True
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Visible = False
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Weight = LWT
            .Line.Transparency = 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is already taken."  _
            & vbCrLf & "Please restart.", vbExclamation, "Restart"
            .Delete
        End If        
    End With
    
  Set shp2 = ws.Shapes.AddShape(9, _
                                rng.Left + 19, _
                                rng.Top + ((rng.Height - DIA) / 2), _
                                DIA, _
                                DIA)
    With shp2
'        Dim sName As String, iCnt As Long
'        Const MAX_TRY = 3  ' max tries
        Do
            If Len(sName) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated."  _
                & vbCrLf & "Please try again.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate"
            End If
            sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="3/3 Enter Name Level 2", _
                                         Default:="Click L2 ", _
                                         Prompt:="", _
                                         Type:=2)
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
        Loop Until ValidateName(sName) Or iCnt = MAX_TRY
        If ValidateName(sName) Then
            .Name = sName
            .Shadow.Visible = False
            .Fill.Visible = True
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Visible = False
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Weight = LWT
            .Line.Transparency = 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is already taken."  _
            & vbCrLf & "Please restart.", vbExclamation, "Restart"
            .Delete
        End If
    End With
    
  MsgBox "Shape Names:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "" & shp1.Name & vbNewLine & _
               "" & shp2.Name, , ""
    
End Sub
'========================================================================

Function ValidateName(ByVal ShpName As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ShpName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ValidateName = (s Is Nothing)
End Function
'========================================================================





Add an UDF to validate user's input.

Sub IPB_AddShapes_Buttons_v3()
    ' your code ...
    
    With shp1
        Dim sName As String
        sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                                     Default:="Click L1 ", _
                                     Prompt:="", _
                                     Type:=2)
        If Not ValidateName(sName) Then
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated. Try again."
            sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                             Default:="Click L1 ", _
                             Prompt:="", _
                             Type:=2)
        End If
        If ValidateName(sName) Then
            .Name = sName
            .Shadow.Visible = False
            .Fill.Visible = True
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Visible = False
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Weight = LWT
            .Line.Transparency = 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated"
            .Delete
        End If
    End With
    
    ' your code ...
    
End Sub

Function ValidateName(ByVal ShpName As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As Shape
    ShpName = UCase(ShpName)
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If UCase(s.Name) = ShpName Then
            ValidateName = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    ValidateName = True
End Function


User may retry X times

    With shp1
        Dim sName As String, iCnt As Long
        Const MAX_TRY = 3  ' max tries
        Do
            If Len(sName) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated." & vbCrLf & "Please try again."
            End If
            sName = Application.InputBox(Title:="2/3 Enter Name Level 1", _
                                         Default:="Click L1 ", _
                                         Prompt:="", _
                                         Type:=2)
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
        Loop Until ValidateName(sName) Or iCnt = MAX_TRY
        If ValidateName(sName) Then
            .Name = sName
            .Shadow.Visible = False
            .Fill.Visible = True
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Visible = False
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            .Line.Weight = LWT
            .Line.Transparency = 0
        Else
            MsgBox "Shape name [" & sName & "] is duplicated"
            .Delete
        End If
    End With


Another option UDF

Function ValidateName(ByVal ShpName As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ShpName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ValidateName = (s Is Nothing)
End Function


And how would you include a "try again"-prompt after a "duplicate"-alert?

The updated code gives users more retry opportunities.

How do you modify "User may retry X times" to work for both shapes?

Duplicate With shp1 ... End With.  Change shp1 > shp2 and inputbox arguments.
